# Getting exception while doing block() on Mono object I got back from ReactiveMongoRepository object

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a service that streams data to a second service that receives stream of objects and saves them to my MongoDB.
 inside my subscribe function on the Flux object that I get from the streaming service I use the save method from the ReactiveMongoRepository interface.
when I try to use the block function and get the data I get the following error :

```
2019-10-11 13:30:38.559  INFO 19584 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:25}] to localhost:27017
2019-10-11 13:30:38.566  INFO 19584 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=6218300}
2019-10-11 13:30:39.158  INFO 19584 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] quote-monitor-service                    : onNext(Quote(id=null, ticker=AAPL, price=164.8, instant=2019-10-11T10:30:38.800Z))
2019-10-11 13:30:39.411  INFO 19584 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] quote-monitor-service                    : cancel()
2019-10-11 13:30:39.429  INFO 19584 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:26}] to localhost:27017
2019-10-11 13:30:39.437  WARN 19584 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil         : Failed to release a message: DefaultHttpContent(data: PooledSlicedByteBuf(freed), decoderResult: success)

io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.toLiveRealRefCnt(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.release(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:138) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at 
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:77) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1494) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at
```

my code:

```
stockQuoteClient.getQuoteStream()
                .log("quote-monitor-service")
                .subscribe(quote -> {
                    Mono<Quote> savedQuote = quoteRepository.save(quote);
                    System.out.println("I saved a quote! Id: " +savedQuote.block().getId());
                });
```

after some digging, I manage to get it to work but I don't understand why it works now.
the  new code:

```
stockQuoteClient.getQuoteStream()
                .log("quote-monitor-service")
                .subscribe(quote -> {
                       Mono<Quote> savedQuote = quoteRepository.insert(quote);
                       savedQuote.subscribe(result ->
                                 System.out.println("I saved a quote! Id :: " + result.getId()));
    });
```

the definition of block(): Subscribe to this Mono and block indefinitely until a next signal is received.

the definition of subscribe(): Subscribe to this Mono and request unbounded demand.

can someone help me understand why the block didn't work and the subscribe worked?
what am I missing here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449889/block-blockfirst-blocklast-are-blocking-error-when-calling-bodytomono-afte

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blocking is bad, since it ties up a thread waiting for a response. It's *very* bad in a reactive framework which has few threads at its disposal, and is designed so that *none* of them should be unnecessarily blocked.

This is the very thing that reactive frameworks are designed to avoid, so in this case it simply stops you doing it:

> block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4

Your new code, in contrast, works asynchronously. The thread isn't blocked, as nothing actually happens until the repository returns a value (and then the lambda that you passed to `savedQuote.subscribe()` is executed, printing out you result to the console.)

However, the new code still isn't optimal / normal from a reactive streams perspective, as you're doing all your logic in your subscribe method. The normal thing to do is to us a series of flatMap/map calls to transform the items in the stream, and use `doOnNext()` for side effects (such as printing out a value):

```
stockQuoteClient.getQuoteStream()
            .log("quote-monitor-service")
            .flatMap(quoteRepository::insert)
            .doOnNext(result -> System.out.println("I saved a quote! Id :: " + result.getId())))
            .subscribe();
```

If you're doing any serious amount of work with reactor / reactive streams, it would be worth reading up on them in general. They're very powerful for non-blocking work, but they do require a different way of thinking (and coding) than more "standard" Java.