# Spring-Boot WebClient block() method returns error java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm trying to fetch value(string) using Spring WebFlux **WebClient**, (Using SpringBoot version 2.4.5,)

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public Mono<String> getData(){
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:9999");
    Mono<String> stringMono = webClient.get()
            .uri("/some/thing")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
    stringMono.subscribe( System.out::println);
    System.out.println("Value : " + stringMono.block()); // this doesn't work,  expecting to return ResponseBody as "Hello World" ,
    return stringMono;
}
```

But getting below error

```
2021-05-11 20:02:15.521 ERROR 55613 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [19114471-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/test"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/test" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1703) ~[reactor-core-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.getData(DemoApplication.java:28) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
```

Reference for block method - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-synchronous

Answer (score 6):

When using Webflux, the whole idea is that you *don't* block - you'll cause massive performance problems if you do (see [here for a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58339681/getting-exception-while-doing-block-on-mono-object-i-got-back-from-reactivemon) that explains why) so the framework explicitly disallows it, throwing an exception if you try.

You also shouldn't subscribe manually - while not a "mortal sin" in the reactive world as blocking is, that's certainly another red flag. Subscription is handled by the framework. You just need to return the `Mono`, and Webflux will subscribe when required to handle your request. In your case your manual subscription means the entire chain will actually be executed *twice* for each request - once to print the result out to the terminal, and once to return the result to the `/test` endpoint.

Instead, if you want a "side-effect" like this (printing out the value when you have it) then you need to alter the reactive chain to do so, using the `doOnNext()` operator. This means you can then do:

```
return webClient.get()
          .uri("/some/thing")
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(String.class)
          .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("Value: " + s));
```

This will ensure the value is printed out to the terminal, but without blocking, and without manually subscribing.

Comment: Michael I agree with your opinion , however I have scenario when response(POJO) of one webClient will be used in next webClient api call, then I how I will handle subsequent api calls ?

Comment: @GautamGarg You simply extend the reactive chain, flat-mapping or transforming the result of this web call into the result of the next web service call. Reactive programming pretty much mandates that you do things this way - breaking outside the reactive chain doesn't allow you to then "react" to the previous result in the pipeline.