# WebClient wait until you get a response of the request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, webclient

I make a request with webClient in spring boot here is the request above:

```
Mono<ClientResponse> clientResponse = webClientBuilder
                .build()
                .post()
                .uri(societe.get(0)
                        .getApi_login())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(
                        identify)
                .exchange();
```

my question is how can i wait the result of the request before executing another instruction

Comment: Are the other instructions dependent on the result? If not, I think that you can just proceed as normal. And If they are dependent, you can use operations such as doOnSuccess or zip it with another etc. Without knowing your use-case, it is hard to give any advice.

Comment: thank you @thinkgruen for the answer. Yes they are the other instructions dependent on the result and the problem these instructions runs before the result and i get errors

Comment: could you add a bit more code so that we can see how the calls are chained?

Answer (score 0):

[How to use WebClient to execute synchronous request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750918/how-to-use-webclient-to-execute-synchronous-request)

Add `.block()`

Something similar like this, I don't use flux too much, also can't test it:

```
Mono<ClientResponse> clientResponse = webClientBuilder
                .build()
                .post()
                .uri(societe.get(0)
                        .getApi_login())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(
                        identify)
                .exchange()
                .block();
```

Comment: First rule of Webflux: If you cannot write non-blocking code - don't use Webflux. This solution makes no sense and if you follow the comments below the (bad) answer you linked, you will eventually end up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456050/3393379)

Comment: Yet, but he asked how to do it. The answer is correct, even if it is not suggested.