# How to create Thymeleaf converter with Mono object

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to create convereter from string to object.

```
@Component
public class PropertyConverter implements Converter<String, PropertyShop> {
    @Autowired
    PropertyShopService propertyShopService;

    @Override
    public PropertyShop convert(@NotNull String id) {
        long idBD = Long.parseLong(id);
      
        return propertyShopService.getPropertyById(idBD); // Mono<PropertyShop>
  
}
```

But from propertyShopService I received `Mono<PropertyShop>`.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a good way in my opinion and I'll prefer returning Mono  instead of extracting PropertyShop from Mono. But if you really need to do that you can use

`return propertyShopService.getPropertyById(idBD).block();`

for more details you can check this [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-from-mono)

Comment: I cant use block. I will receive error.

Comment: Can you please share that error ?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.svinogr.flier.model.PropertyShop] for value '1'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-tcp-nio-1

Comment: this error has been explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449889/block-blockfirst-blocklast-are-blocking-error-when-calling-bodytomono-afte . they have discussed why using block or subscribe is a bad idea too. so you may need to return Mono itself however if you need you can change the type returned via mono. but for a reactive Application we should be returning Mono or Flux only.

Comment: I tried returning Mono but then nothing is converted. There is no error, but as if nothing is returned. " return propertyShopService.getPropertyById(idBD).flatMap(propertyShop -> { System.out.println("convert"+ propertyShop); return Mono.just(propertyShop); }); "

Comment: Can you share the way you are using to test that? are you using reactor's stepVerifier to verify or some other way?

Comment: I was hoping to see a message in the console that I wrote to flatMap(propertyShop -> { System.out.println("convert"+ propertyShop); return Mono.just(propertyShop));    :)

Comment: May be you need to learn more about working of Mono and Flux. for this scenario I guess there is no terminal operation that's why that block with print statement is not executing.
You can write a test using reactor stepVerifier to see if it is working. 
May be you can refer https://dzone.com/articles/spring-5-web-reactive-flux-and-mono or any other basic tutorial to learn how to test this.