# How to return just a String using Webflux - webclient?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I would like to make this call and return a string
but I'm having this error:

***"java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking,
which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3"***

I dont understand why am I doing wrong?
WebClient supports asynchronous as well as synchronous calls.

This a springboot project with just 3 dependencies.

How can I return just a string like a normal synchronous call?

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String home() {
String resp = webclient.get()                             
                       .uri(ANY_URL).retrieve()
                       .bodyToMono(String.class)
                       .block();
return resp;

 }


}

pom.xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking error when calling bodyToMono AFTER exchange()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449889/block-blockfirst-blocklast-are-blocking-error-when-calling-bodytomono-afte)

Comment: To make it work asynchronously/error vanish: you have to add `spring-boot-starter-web` (dependency), i suppose.

Comment: ..to keep it reactive, just: return `Mono<String>` (without "blocking")

Comment: It worked by adding spring-boot-starter-web, do you know why it was needed? @xerx593

Comment: In short: This adds "servlet/filters", which "support blocking" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding `spring-boot-starter-web`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your goal but the whole idea of Webflux is to create non-blocking reactive services. `WebClient` support both async and sync usage but the error you are getting is from reactive controller. There is no reason to block in your example - just change return type from `String` to `Mono<String>`.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public Mono<String> home() {
String resp = webclient.get()                             
       .uri(ANY_URL).retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(String.class);
 }
```

The intuition behind this is

- use `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and `WebClient` in async mode to create reactive services. Controller should return `Mono` or `Flux`. The caveat here is that your logic should be reactive (async) end-to-end to get full advantage of the Reactive API.
- add `spring-boot-starter-web` if you want to build non-reactive service and just use `WebClient` in sync (blocking) mode as your Http client.